# Tracking editor responsible for creating a video

Tags: video-editor

I have videos created by me in two different editing software with the same extension. Is it possible to trace the source of these files?

Comment: Adobe apps may wrire XMP tags in the output which conceivably could carry ID info, but usually I don't see any.